# How to generate an image from pixel values taken from a .csv file?

Tags: python, matlab

I have a csv file that has RGB values in each row. I want to generate a 512 x 512 image with each pixel value taken from the rows of the csv. How do I go about doing this? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
  2.053  163.5011  0.0522
  2.053  163.4489  0.0517
  2.053  163.3972  0.0511
  2.053  163.3461  0.0506
  2.053  163.2955  0.0501
  ...
```

Comment: please add a programming language and image format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the code should be something like that

```
import numpy as np
import PIL
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load the data
im_l = np.genfromtxt('image.csv', delimiter=',')
# resphape the data
img = np.reshape(im_l, (256,256,3)) # change 256's according to your data

# visualize the data
plt.figure
plt.imshow(img)

# finally save the image as jpg file
image = PIL.Image.fromarray(img.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
image.save('my_im.jpg')
```

Answer (score 2):

Tags specify Python and matlab, I just picked the former since that's what I know. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#values = np.loadtxt("D://tempCode/test.txt") # for reading from file
values = np.random.random(size=(512,512,3)) # random pixels
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(values)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

The critical bit is realisng how your data is structured, i.e. is it given row-by-row or column-by-column. Then you'll need to call values.reshape(new_shape) on it to make it work with imshow. Have a look here for the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html).